# Create a case during account approval process

Tags: approval-process

I have created an account approval process, and as soon as the approval process is kicked off, I would like to create a case. 
Is this possible without code?

As per the below comment, I have used process builder, which I think will work. However, I am not sure how I must link the case to the Account. I have done the following:
[image: Process Builder]

In fact, I checked and I could see that no case was created at all. However, my Process Builder criteria look fine:
[image: Process Builder]

The Account Status is also set correctly on the account, so the process builder should be triggered.

Tia, Lily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the process builder to accomplish this.

When the account approval process is kicked off, update a status field on the Account (e.g. 'Pending approval'). Then create a new process in the process builder that creates a case whenever an Account has it's status field updated to 'Pending approval'. No code required :)

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my description, as I cannot get the process builder to work correctly.

Comment: Have you set the process to start: only when a record is created or
when a record is created or edited? You can find this setting by clicking the Dark Blue rectangle with Account in it.

Comment: Yes, it is set to: when a record is created or edited
Could it be because the record is locked during an approval process, that a case cannot be created for this account?

Comment: On the field update on the approval process that changes the Account status, have you ticked the option 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change'

Comment: No that's not ticked - should it be?

Comment: Yes. This needs to be ticked to kick off the process.